# postgres cast | convert interval to iso_8601 format

Tags: php, postgresql, datetime, iso8601

In pg month could be 'mon' or 'month' in php 'mon' is for monday.

myinterval is a interval column on the db.

how to make pg output

```
`SELECT myinterval FROM table` = 1 year 6 mons
```

to

```
`SELECT myinterval FROM table` = P1Y6M
```

I read about `intervalstyle` but I'm working with existing code so I can't mess with some lines, with intervalstyle it will change for the whole session

Comment: I wondering why is your first line relevant to solve the query?

Comment: because if you feed that to php it will count 1 year and 6 mondays instead of 1 year and 6 months, I can pass 'mon' or 'month' TO pg, but all responses FROM pg is 'mon'.

'P1YM' it's how php deals with interval 'Period of 1 Year and 6 Months'

Comment: But that is irrelevent. postgres will return a string no matter what

Comment: yes, but is a string that php understand.

Comment: You already found the solution: [the `IntervalStyle` option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-INTERVALSTYLE) controls [the output of interval values](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT). You can mess around with [`to_char()` formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html), but creating a pattern for ISO8601 period format is harder than it seems.

Comment: for now my solution is this `pg_query(SET intervalstyle TO iso_8601; SELECT myinterval FROM table;RESET intervalstyle)`, it's a simplified version of my query, but i'm not comfortable doing this, it looks wrong.

Comment: If you are worried about setting the default for the entire engine, you can also do it [per database and/or per role](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-SQL-COMMAND-INTERACTION) level.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for answering this question so late, but I just encountered this same issue in my legacy code base. I solved this by using a transaction and setting the interval style for the duration of the transaction:

```sql
BEGIN;

SET LOCAL intervalstyle = 'iso_8601';
SELECT (INTERVAL '6 years 5 months 4 days 3 hours 2 minutes 1 second')::text;

COMMIT;
```

This outputs `P6Y5M4DT3H2M1S`

If I run this directly afterwards:

```sql
SELECT (INTERVAL '6 years 5 months 4 days 3 hours 2 minutes 1 second')::text;
```

Then I get `6 years 5 mons 4 days 03:02:01`

Therefore the session's interval style isn't affected.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function wrapper to parse the interval:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION iso_8601_format(i INTERVAL)
    RETURNS TEXT
    AS $$
        BEGIN
            SET LOCAL intervalstyle = 'iso_8601';
            RETURN i::TEXT;
        END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then use it to parse the intervals

```sql
postgres=# SELECT iso_8601_format('5 minutes'::INTERVAL);
 iso_8601_format 
----------------
 PT5M
(1 row)
```